# how to fix wrong alertDialog on a Click?

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog

I have 2 TextViews showing on the main UI.  I associate each TextView to a unique clickListener that launches a unique AlertDialog for the user to make a selection.  The first TextView is launching the second layout for the second AlertDialog rather than the expected first layout for the first AlertDialog.  What am I missing here?

```
activity_main.xml file

...
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/fList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="filter"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
    />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/qList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="quickList"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
        android:gravity="center"
    />

MainActivity.java file

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView mTextViewFilter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fList);
        TextView mTextViewQuickList = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.qList);

        mTextViewFilter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogFilter = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflaterFilter = getLayoutInflater();

            final ViewGroup nullParent = null;
            // the AlertDialog layout for the first TextView click.
            final View dialogLayoutFilter = inflaterFilter.inflate(R.layout.filter_main, nullParent);
            alertDialogFilter.setView(dialogLayoutFilter);
            final AlertDialog dialogFilter = alertDialogFilter.show();
            ...
         }
     });   

     mTextViewQuickList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            final ViewGroup nullParent = null;
            // the AlertDialog layout for the second TextView click.
            final View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entire_layout, nullParent);
            alertDialog.setView(dialogLayout);
            final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.show();
            ... 
        }
    });        

entire_layout.xml    
...
<RelativeLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="380dp"
android:minHeight="160dp"  >    

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewX"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:contentDescription="x"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/FullList"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewX"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
    android:text="Show entire list"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullNewest"
    android:layout_below="@+id/FullList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:text="Created ...  />
```

```
filter_main.xml
...
<RelativeLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="380dp"
android:minHeight="280dp"  >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewX"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:contentDescription="x"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Filter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewX"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
    android:text="Filter..."  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/AllDos"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Filter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:text="All..."  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/AllBuys"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AllDos"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:text="All..."  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/AllWork"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AllBuys"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:text="All..."  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/AllHome"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AllWork"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:text="All..."  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/AllWaitingfor"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AllHome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:text="All..."  />
```

Comment: Why are you not showing `AlertDialog` directly instead of assigning it to new `AlertDialog`? Or instead of `.show()` use `.create()` then show dialog calling `.show()` method?

Comment: @Yupi Android newbie here.  Can you show me an example of AlertDialog directly and an example of .create() then .show()?

Comment: try with converting this line `final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.show();` into just `alertDialog.show();` in both `OnClickListeners` or you can keep that line but instead of `show()` call `create();` like this:   `final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();` then you can call `dialog.show();`

Comment: Ok I changed last line in ClickListener to:  "final AlertDialog dialogFilter = alertDialogFilter.create();"  Then I added:  "dialogFilter.show();"  No luck, same result.

Comment: Any chance your layouts `entire_layout` and `filter_main` are have same design or xml code?

Comment: No, I doublechecked them.  I will add their code above in the question.

Comment: Update also rest of code in `ClickListeners`

Comment: Updated.  The rest of the code in ClickListeners is only for when the user makes a selection from a set of choices once the AlertDialog is open.

Comment: Then there is possibility that only one `TextView` is catching the click. Put `breakpoints` in both and test or use `Log` to see are both clicks are catched.

Comment: I agree, that is probably what is happening.  I will try your suggestion but still not sure how to fix even if one TextView is catching the click.

Comment: Make sure your `TextViews` are not overlapping and put in both: `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: Ah, maybe the clickListener for the qList TextView is overlapping the other TextView because its layout width attribute is set to match_parent.

Comment: If your parent layout is RelativeLayout then probably that is the issue because RelativeLayout allows overlapping.

Comment: Yes, it's a RelativeLayout.  I need the qList TextView to be centered in the parent.  Should I try a LinearLayout instead to avoid ovetlapping?

Comment: You could use LinearLayout it will prevent overlapping or you could add to your qList TextView ‘android:layout_below=“@+id/fList”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your textviews' parent is but since you are using attributes like:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

I guess it is a `RelativeLayout`.

Since you aren't using neither an orientation nor a relative position, I suppose your TextViews are both on the same line, with just a different margin top, but the **quick list** TextView has width match_parent and gravity center

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
```

So what's happening is something like this:

[image]

And your click always triggers the second TextView that covers entirely the first one.

To fix it change your **quick list** TextView this way:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="quickList"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

With the attributes:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

It will be centered but not overlapping the first TextView.

I hope this could help, if instead I am wrong and your `activity_main.xml` file differs, please update your code so that it can be easier figure out any alternative problem.

Comment: Yes it's a RelativeLayout.  I will try your suggestion and then circle back.